# GCC "Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered" (full code included)

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, c++11

When I build my project the compiler outputs the below (error message at the bottom). I ported the code over from Visual Studio (where it compiles fine when using the Intel Compiler).

Can someone please help?

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 70ms)

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/New Volume/Project/Proj'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Proj
make[2]: Entering directory `/media/New Volume/Project/Proj'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/ABS.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/ABS.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/ABS.o ABS.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Drv.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Drv.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Drv.o Drv.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/FD.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/FD.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/FD.o FD.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/FM.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/FM.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/FM.o FM.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Fin.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Fin.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Fin.o Fin.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Fut.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Fut.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Fut.o Fut.cpp
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Idx.o.d
g++ -m64   -c -g -I/usr/include/boost -I/usr/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Idx.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Idx.o Idx.cpp
‘
Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered.
```

This is Idx header and source files (I presume `Idx` caused it??):

```
#ifndef Idx_H
#define Idx_H


#include "Stk.h"

#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Idx
{
    public:
        Idx();
        Idx(string sid);
        Idx(string sid, vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > IdxInstslist, unordered_map<string,double> Idxweights);
                ~Idx();

        vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > getIdxInstsList();
        void addInstToIdx(boost::shared_ptr<Stk> s, double weight);
        void setIdxInstsList(vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > indinstrlist);
        double getIdxStockweight(string sid);

    private:
        vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > IdxInstslist;
        unordered_map<string,double> Idxweightsdict;
        string sid;
};

#endif
```

and source:

```
#include "Idx.h"

Idx::Idx(){}

Idx::Idx(string id){
    sid = id;
}

Idx::Idx(string id,vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > IdxInstlist, unordered_map<string,double> Idxweights){
    sid = id;
    IdxInstslist = IdxInstlist;
    Idxweightsdict = Idxweights;
}

Idx::~Idx(){}

void Idx::addInstToIdx(boost::shared_ptr<Stk>  s, double weight){
    if(Idxweightsdict.count(s->getSecurityID())==0)
    {
        IdxInstslist.push_back(s);
        Idxweightsdict[s->getSecurityID()] = weight;
    }
}

vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > Idx::getIdxInstsList(){
    return IdxInstslist;
}

void Idx::setIdxInstsList(vector<boost::shared_ptr<Stk> > indinstrlist){
    IdxInstslist = indinstrlist;
}

double Idx::getIdxStockweight(string sid){
    double weight = 0;

    if(Idxweightsdict.count(sid) == 1){
        weight = Idxweightsdict[sid];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot retrieve Idx weight for Inst not part of Idx" << endl;
    }

    return weight;
}
```

Comment: compiler version? Did you check on bugzilla?

Comment: What boost version?  Try a different version of boost... they are always adding new workarounds for compiler bugs.

Answer (score 2):

`Internal compiler error` means that there is a bug in the compiler -- it's not a problem with your code, although it could be triggered by something you are doing.

Could be related to this [already reported bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57086).

You could try getting a later version of the compiler, or just a different version of the compiler if that's possible.

Comment: I'm using GCC and G++ 4.7 :( ... ?

Comment: You could also try an earlier version if you don't need any new functionality provided by 4.7.

Comment: @PeterAlexander I need at least 4.7 because I am using c++11 features.